# jQuery validation on radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two radio buttons in my form for gender selection.

I am using [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin for validation. 
When I apply validation on radio button, this plugin places the error label between the two radio buttons.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wyFQp/1/

HTML:

```
<head>
    <body>
        <form id='registration_form'>
            <input type="radio" value="M" name="gender" class="gender" id="genderm"
            />Male
            <input type="radio" value="F" name="gender" class="gender ml_10" id="genderf"
             />Female
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
```

How can I place the error label after both radio buttons?  Or at least on some decent place?

Comment: You haven't said which is your desired location though

Comment: after both the radio buttons..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an error label in your markup where you'd like the error to show:

```
<label class="error" generated="true" for="gender" style="display:none;"></label>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wyFQp/13/)

When associating it with radio inputs, the error label's `for` attribute corresponds to radios' `name` - this facilitates things as radios with the same name will only have one radio selected at a time and one error label associated with the group.
For text inputs (and `select`/`textarea`/`type="checkbox"`) though, the `id` must be used.

---

Another less hackish way is to use the [`errorPlacement`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) option with an error container, e.g.:

```
<div id="genderErrorContainer"></div>
```

```
$("#registration_form").validate({
    rules: {[...]},
    messages: {[...]},
    submitHandler: fn,
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.prop('name') === 'gender') {
            error.appendTo('#genderErrorContainer');
        }
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wyFQp/15/)

Of course, you can also use other DOM manipulation methods to add the error element to the DOM, for example `.append`, `.prepend`, `.after`, `insertAfter`, `.before`, `.insertBefore` combined with DOM traversal based on the `element` that originated the validation error, which may not require extra markup depending on your HTML structure.

Comment: @Edga Not really, IDs are how labels are supposed to work *but* `jQuery.validate` uses `name` for radios instead.

Comment: Does this plugin looks for error label before putting it's own label ?

Comment: @JAVAGeek Exactly. For regular text inputs you use the ID instead of name though. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I followed your suggestion and it did work. However, in the spirit of separating content from style from functionality is there a way to place the error label at an exact position without having to manually add markup? Gave your answer an upvote. Thanks in advance.